# What is sudo password

Tags: sudo, authentication

Actually i'm a new user i'm getting problem in knowing sudo password
First of all, What is it? Secondly, Where do I get it? I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

Its the same password you use to login into your user.